# How to hide a logged area content from Chrome inspect if not logged in

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, logging

Basically I have an Angular 7 project, it is a website for a home and a logged area.
The content of the logged area, accessible via OAuth, must be visible only to logged users.

The problem is that, from the home page, if I inspect I can't find the logged content in the HTML part (and this is correct), but if I navigate to main.js under source, I can find that content in a module.export.

What I am doing right now is that:

I have a component called LoggedComponent that appears on the main component only if the *ngIf='logged' is satisfied.
logged is taken from a service and it is updated correctly if the user is logged in or not.
If logged is true, then the component is loaded.

But how can I hide the content of the LoggedComponent from a user that can inspect my code from chrome?
My website is all under a homepage, I did not use Router, is it the solution?

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: So guys the problem is that if you are NOT logged in, but you inspect my code from the home page, you can see the LOGGEDCOMPONENT content. This is not correct, it must be visible to logged users only! Help please :)

Comment: What do you mean by inspect code? Source code or the DOM? You can't hide source code, you can only obfuscate it to make it hard to read

Comment: if it is inside an ngIf the user cannot see it even with inspect code.

Comment: What people usually do is that all the hidden data is only accessible by going through an API, and you need to be logged in to be able to retrieve the data from that API.

Comment: I mean that the video can be seen if you inspect the code, go to the source and check into the main.js file. Even if I have built the project with --prod, if you do CTRL+F and search for VIDEO, then you will see the video tag. I want it to be hidden